# send the dropdown option selected values from one view page to another view page in codeigniter using ajax or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my controller ie home.php,

```
function search($collg_id = '', $id = '') {
    $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
    $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
    if (empty($data['course_offrd_name'])) {
        $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
    } else {
        $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered');
        $data['course_offrd_name'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
    }
}
```

This is my model.php,

```
function get_data_wheree($table) {
    $this->db->select('course_offrd_name, collg_id');
    $this->db->group_by('course_offrd_name');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
}
```

This is my source view page ie index.php dropdown page

```
<div class = "col-md-2">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <select class = "course" name = "course_offrd-name[]" id = "course_offrd_name" class = "form-control">
                <option value = "">Select</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($coursedata as $val) {
                    ?>              
                    <option value="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>">
                        <?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>
                    </option> 
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select.course").change(function () {
            var selectedCourse = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            alert("You have selected the course - " + selectedCourse);
        });
    });
</script>
<!--this is my  second view page ie search.php where myselected option should display--> 
<form class="form-horizontal well" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>search" method="post" role="form">
    <span>
        <?php foreach ($coursedata as $val) {
            ?>
            <p>
                <input class="with-gap filter_course CheckCourse" name="course_offrd_name[]" multiple type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name; ?>"  value="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name ?>" 
                       <?php
                       if (!empty($courserecord))
                           if (count($courserecord) == 1)
                               if ($courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name'] == $val->course_offrd_name) {
                                   echo $courserecord[0]['course_offrd_name'];
                                   echo "checked";
                               } else {

                               }
                       ?> />
                <label for="<?php echo $val->course_offrd_name ?>"></label>
            </p>
        <?php } ?> 
    </span>
    <br>
</form>
```

I want to  send the dropdown option selected values from one view page to another view page in codeigniter using ajax or jQuery.
The option value which is selected should be send from index.php to search.php.It should just display the value name in search.php
If required will provide more code.
How can be it done ?
Now I have code in search() function.
I have made changes in code.
Please see this search function.
Thank in advance!

Comment: we are unable to read your code please do proper indentation of your code and your info text

Comment: @M.Hemant CHECK THE CODE I HAVE INDENTED PROPERLY ....

Comment: There is nothing in search() function?

Comment: @M.Hemant i have made changes in the search function code...see this